# Cannot find module 'discord.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

When I start my discord bot I get an error on the console:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
Require stack:
- /home/container/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/container/index.js' ]
}
```

But if there is an "index.js"

Comment: It looks like you don't have discord.js installed. Make sure to run `npm install discord.js` in the root of your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install discord.js, in your console type `npm install discord.js`